# how to Showing counts in echarts4r `e_pie` pie ,charts bar charts in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, pie-chart, echarts4r

I have a column that contains 4 variables which are(  Bad , Good , Very Good , Excellent )

I need to count how much they repeats in that column and compare each of them and presint to me in pie chart and bar chart in echarts4r

For example : `df <- data.frame( var = c("low","low","low","high") )` i want the same result as `ggplot(df)+geom_bar(aes(var))`.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput(your_dataframe)` in your question above?

Comment: for example :  


  df <- data.frame(
    
    var = c("low","low","low","hight")
  )
  

i want the same result   at this formula

ggplot(df)+geom_bar(aes(var))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a dataframe which shows the count per var and after that you can use this in `e_chart` with `e_bar` like this:

```
df <- data.frame( var = c("low","low","low","hight") )
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)

df_result <- df %>% 
  count(var) %>% 
  arrange(n)

plot <- df_result %>%
  e_charts(x = var) %>%
  e_bar(n, legend = FALSE, name = "var")
```

Output:

[image]

Which is the same result using `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(df)+geom_bar(aes(var))
```

[image]